# won't boot after 4.2.0-30-generic kernel update

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, 15.10

I'm running 15.10.  Yesterday I had a message that there were updates available and I upgraded.  Among the updates was kernel 4.2.0-30-generic.  It wanted to restart but I chose restart later.  This morning when I turned on the machine I went through the grub menu normally (Windows is also installed) and it booted to a black screen and stopped before the splash screen and login.  From the black screen I can't <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> or do anything really and there is no disk activity.  From looking at `syslog`, it seems that the system time was wrong, but other than that, everything seems to have loaded properly, it just never got to the login screen.  I restarted after a while and went through the grub menu to recovery mode and ran some of the diagnostics which didn't find anything except the system time.  I let it continue with normal boot and it booted fine.  Once logged in, I ran `apt-get update/upgrade/autoremove/dist-upgrade/clean` and rebooted.  Tried the default option and it booted to the same black screen.  Tried kernel 4.2.0-30 (upstart) which froze.  Tried 4.2.0-27-generic which boots no problem.  I tried to run `grub-script-check -v` from the terminal but it didn't do anything and I eventually had to `^C`.  I've never tried to run it before but I would imagine that it shouldn't take too long.  The man page said it just checks the config file for syntax.  What do I do?  Uninstall/Reinstall kernel 4.2.0-30?

Comment: Uninstall 4.2.0-30 and boot with 4.2.0-27. It is a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Kernel 4.2.0-30 has a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1548587).  Uninstall it by issuing the following commands in the terminal.

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-image-4.2.0-30-generic
sudo update-grub2
```

Comment: There is no need to update grub. It will be run either way.

Comment: When uninstalling, a message was displayed advising me to update grub...

Comment: Well, each linux-image uninstall triggers update-grub. But that's OK.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the Linux Kernel version 4.2.0-30 has a bug and is currently being fixed. See this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1548587

A temporary solution (until the bug is fixed) was to remove the version 4.2.0-30 kernel. This should revert you back to whatever the last version that was working. The command below worked for me:

`apt-get --purge remove linux-image-4.2.0-30-generic linux-image-extra-4.2.0-30-generic`

For reference, both versions 4.2.0.27 and 4.2.0.25 worked for me without a problem